# Subscription Website Software

Tags: asp.net, subscriptions

I've been tasked with developing a website that requires a subscription fee to access certain areas of the website, to be paid quarterly. It may also be necessary to pay out to members a small amount but nothing is confirmed yet. The website will be built in ASP.Net. Does anyone know of any subscription systems I can build on top of? Preferably with a busy community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Spreedly; http://www.spreedly.com/

They have a fantastic subscription based system that's easy to modify and an API for you to introduce that functionality into any application you build.  They handle all the payments and credit card bits and just fund a specified PayPal account.

Comment: Looks great, shame no WorldPay gateway